# Permanently pointing to a memory

Tags: c, windows, pointers, memory

I need access to the integer located at (0xC0EC5A0 + 0x00EC) but ReadProcessMemory will only return me the value of that integer when I need to save a pointer to that value in my program so that I can reference it easier. If I can't save a pointer to that address location I would have to call ReadProcessMemory many times a second which seems inefficient.

```
DWORD pid;

printf("Enter the process id: ");
scanf("%d", &pid);
printf("\n");

HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid); //PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS gives all access, PROCESS_VM_READ gives reading access

if(hProcess == NULL) {
    printf("OpenProcess Failed GetLastError: %d \n", GetLastError());
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return pressToClose(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int valueOne;
ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID) (entityObject + 0x00EC), &valueOne, sizeof(int), NULL);
```

entityObject is equal to 0xC0EC5A0 and when I run this code it returns the correct value located at that memory address inside of the correct process but I want to be able to save a pointer to that memory location is that even possible? Do I really have to loop through this multiple times a second to ensure I always have the updated values?

Comment: @RaymondChen So without injecting into the process I would have to loop? What if I had to make like 100 ReadProcessCalls many times a second would that create strain on my program?

Comment: As with most performance questions, the only way to know is to try it and measure.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help I will just make a loop.